# PMD: Commandline to analyze C Code

Tags: c, pmd, cpd

I want to use [PMD 4.2.5](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html) to find duplicates in my C code. I use the example commandline from their documentation:

```
java net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.CPD --minimum-tokens 100 --files C:\src --language cpp
```

this gives me the error:

```
Can't find the custom format --language: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I tried a lot of different other things too, none worked. The GUI version of the PMD works nicely.

What commandline do i have to use to get PMD to detect duplicate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line you can pass a category for a given language (here [apex](/questions/tagged/apex)) to pmd

```
// best practice
pmd check -d C:\src\ -f html -R category/apex/bestpractices.xml -r C:\src\best.html
// security
pmd check -d C:\src\ -f html -R category/apex/security.xml -r C:\src\security.html
// error prone
pmd check -d C:\src\ -f html -R category/apex/errorprone.xml -r C:\src\errorprn.html
```

You can also combine the categories

```
pmd check -d C:\src\ -f html 
         -R category/apex/bestpractices.xml, 
            category/apex/codestyle.xml, category/apex/design.xml, 
            category/apex/documentation.xml, category/apex/errorprone.xml, 
            category/apex/performance.xml, category/apex/security.xml 
         -r C:\src\PMD_Report_all_categories.html
```

The categories available for a language can be found by unpacking the jar file for your language below `...\pmd-bin-7.0.0-rc3\lib`.

I could not find any rules for [c](/questions/tagged/c)

- neither on the page [3rd party rulesets](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_3rdpartyrulesets.html)
- nor below [Making rulesets](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html) any page for a language specific rule
- i could not match any files below the folder `pmd-bin-7.0.0-rc3\liblib` to [c](/questions/tagged/c) (see screen)

[image: pmd lib folder rulesets]

Answer (score 2):

It seems it wants to load a class to do the language-specific parsing; make sure your CLASSPATH is set up properly.